# How to get the exact position of string one into string 2 c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like this `String Str1 ="44444444.44"` and need the exact position of `.`.

Actually I'm using `String.Compare(Str1, Str2)`, but it return some strange results, what is the proper function in C# to do This?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is simply

```
int pos = Str1.IndexOf(Str2);
```

The string method [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) returns the position of the string passed as argument inside the string used as source. If the argument is not present then the return value will be -1.

Keep in mind that in a more complex search you have to account for case differences and CultureInfo peculiarities. The numerous IndexOf overloads allow you to use this method in a variety of different conditions

Answer (score 4):

What about [string.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx)?

> Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of a specified
>   Unicode character or string within this instance. The method returns
>   -1 if the character or string is not found in this instance.